# Slim query parameter

Tags: php, slim

I want to add a query parameter in my GET Route, which is this one:

```
$app->get('/rooms', function (ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $args) {

    try {

        $room = new \Riecken\PBS\controller\RoomController();
        $result = $room->getRoomsWithDetails();
        $response = $response->withJson($result);
        $response = $response->withStatus(200);
        return $response;
    }catch(Exception $e) {

        $response->getBody()->write($e->getMessage());
        return $response->withStatus($e->getCode());

    }

});
```

What I want to do is that I only want to execute this function when I type "expandAll".

I googled it and I could find something in the Slim documentation:
https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/request.html

But I dont know how to implement it.

So in my case:

If "expandAll" I want to execute the function you see above (getRoomWithDetails(), else I want to execute another function.
Is that possible?

Thanky you very much!

Comment: I'm not an expert but Slim uses [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) as routing engine and its docs do not mention the ability to define routes based on standard URL parameters (`?foo=bar`), only inline "pretty" ones (`/user/123`). You can implement your own parser but it feels like too much trouble. Perhaps a simple `if()` within the route or a "pretty" param will solve the problem without so much hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pass the required query parameters to getRoomsWithDetails or you just add a if condition.

#### Example

```
$app->get('/rooms', function (ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $args) {

    try {
        $expandAll = $request->getParam('expandAll');

        $room = new \Riecken\PBS\controller\RoomController();

        if ($expandAll) {
            $result = $room->getRoomsWithDetails();
        } else {
            $result = $room->anotherMethod();
        }

        $response = $response->withJson($result);
        $response = $response->withStatus(200);

        return $response;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $response = $response->withJson(['error' => ['message' => $e->getMessage()]]);
        return $response->withStatus(500);

    }

});
```